# Should synchronous code called by Promise .then create a new Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I've implemented some code, where asynchronous code is followed by some synchronous functions.  For example:

```
function processSomeAsyncData() {
  asyncFuncCall()
    .then(syncFunction)
    .catch(error);
}
```

If I understand correctly `then` is also a Promise. Then, should I create a promise in the synchronous code as well?

```
function syncFunction() {
  const p = new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
    //Do some sync stuff
    ...
    resolve(data);
  }
  return p;
}
```

If that isn't necessary, how do you reject the promise from the synchronous code if an error occurred?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to create a new promise explicitly. There is an easier way.

This example is contrived because it will never fail, but the point is that you don't have to create a promise and you don't have to return a resolve(val).

```
function syncFunction() {
  var j = "hi"
  if(j){
    return j;
  }
  return new Error('i am an error');
}
```

This will work:

```
asyncFunction()
  .then(syncFunction);
```

But if you did it the other way around:

```
syncFunction()
  .then(asyncFunction);
```

You would have to define your syncFunction as:

```
function syncFunction() {

  var j = "hi"
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(j){
      return resolve(j);
    }
    return reject('error');
  })  
}
```

**Edit:** To prove to all you non believers out there, give this guy a shot locally on your computer. Proves that you have these many options available to you. :)

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');


function b(h) {
    if(h){
        return h;
    }
    return Promise.resolve('hello from b');
}

function a(z) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
        if(z){return resolve(z)};
        return resolve('hello from a');
    })
}

a().then(b).then(x => console.log(x)).catch(e => console.log(e));
b().then(a).then(x => console.log(x)).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Comment: In your second example `new Promise` doesn't required, `Promise.resolve` and `Promise.reject` functions should be used instead.

Comment: In your first bit of code, returning either a promise or a value will certainly not allow for chaining with `.then` afterwards.

Comment: I'm making a quick test locally on my computer to prove this. Gimme a sec. :)

Comment: Done, check it out @nils.

Comment: @nils yes it will, it's perfectly valid to return non-promise values from `then` handlers. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Chaining): _"Values returned from the onFulfilled or onRejected callback functions **will be automatically wrapped in a resolved promise**"_

Comment: My bad, I misread a part of the answer. I somehow figured the first version of the `syncFunction` was supposed to run, when it was just an example.

Comment: A synchronous function should throw on error, not return a rejected promise! Exceptions get converted to rejections inside `.then` functions anyway, so there is never a need to accommodate asynchronous callers in this way.  Synchronous functions may be called from synchronous code and should fail synchronously. Encapsulation rules.

Comment: You bring up a good point jib, a function that returns a promise, even if it's just a reject case, is no longer a sync function. It should definitely throw an error in the first function i wrote. I'm going to edit that.

Answer (score 6):

No. Synchronous functions may be called from synchronous code and should always fail synchronously! They need not conform to asynchronous callers in any way. If an error occurs just throw an error. Try it:

```js
var asyncFuncCall = () => Promise.resolve();

function syncFunction() {
  throw new Error("Fail");
}

asyncFuncCall()
  .then(syncFunction)
  .catch(e => console.log("Caught: " + e.message));
```

This works because an exception thrown by a function passed to a `.then` is converted to a rejection of the promise it is supposed to return.

Additionally, any value returned by a function passed to a `.then` is converted to a promise resolved with that value. The promise code calling the function takes care of this.

This lets you mix synchronous and asynchronous code without problems:

```
asyncFuncCallOne()
  .then(() => {
    var x = syncFunction();
    return asyncFuncCallTwo(x);
  })
  .catch(e => console.log(e.message));
```

Answer (score 2):

It's optional.

If you return a promise from the `syncFunction`, then your original promise will resolve only after the new promise resolves and any value returned by the new promise will be passed to the next `then` in the chain.

If you return a non-Promise value, that will be passed to the next `then` in the chain.

To reject from within `syncFunction`, just throw an exception.

Comment: If `syncFunction` returns a promise, it should be renamed to `asyncFunction`.