# Mix synchronous and asynchronous by Promise.then is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

Here is my code:

```
private loadingData() {
   var promise = new Promise<any>((resolve) => 
   {
       resolve();
   });
   promise.then(() => {
       this.asyncServiceCall();
   })
   .then(() => this.syncFunctionThree())
};
```

The asynchronous method `asyncServiceCall` actually returns a Promise.

```
private asyncServiceCall(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve) = > {
        resolve();
    }).then(() => {
       this.functionOne()
       })
      .then(() => {
       this.functionTwo();
    });
}
```

Okay, let's look at `functionOne` and `functionTwo`. They are both returning Promise.

```
private functionOne() {
   return new Promise((resolve) => {
    this.user['load'] = true;
    this.service['user'].get().subscribe(d => 
  {
     this.user['d'] = d;
  },
  error => console.error(error),
  () => {
     this.role['load']=false;
   });
  resolve();
});
}

private functionTwo() {
   return new Promise((resolve) => {
    this.service['name'].get().subscribe(d => 
  {
     this.name['d'] = d;
  },
  resolve();
});
}
```

The third method `syncFunctionThree` will use the data `this.user['d']` and `this.name['d']` to have some business logic. So I want to call `functionOne` and `functionTwo` first then call `syncFunctionThree`.

By [the accepted answer without creating new Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38796828/should-synchronous-code-called-by-promise-then-create-a-new-promise), I don't get lucky. I found that the 
`syncFunctionThree` was called before the asynchronous methods.

So help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an important part of calling promises inside `then()` ... you need to `return` those promises or the `then()` will resolve immediately and go to the next then() in the chain. That's why functionThree is firing before the asynchronous promise functions resolve

```
private loadingData() {
   var promise = new Promise<any>((resolve) => 
   {
       resolve();
   });
   promise.then(() => {
      // return the promise this function returns
      return this.asyncServiceCall();
     // ^^^^
   })
    // this then() won't fire until asyncServiceCall resolves in previous then()
   .then((resultFromPriorThen) => this.syncFunctionThree())
}
```

---

Now you don't really need this first promise in `loadingData()` because you already have a promise to work with returned by `asyncServiceCall()` and can simplify it to:

```
private loadingData(): Promise<any> {      
   return this.asyncServiceCall().then(()=>this.syncFunctionThree());
}
```

Now to fix `asyncServiceCall()` the same way:

```
private asyncServiceCall(): Promise<any> {   
   return this.functionOne().then(()=>this.functionTwo());   
}
```

---

Final note: Need to add  a `catch()` in `loadingData()` in case one of the asynchronous operations has a problem

Comment: `return this.functionOne().then(this.functionTwo)` or `return this.functionOne().then(this.functionTwo())`? Do we need add `()` at the end of `functionTwo`?

Comment: @Bigeyes you have two choices: `return this.functionOne().then(this.functionTwo.bind(this))` or `return this.functionOne().then(() => this.functionTwo())`. Your version won't work as you expect

Comment: But I guess something wrong...in `private asyncServiceCall()`, `this.functionOne().then(()=>this.functionTwo());   
}` is grayed. The compiler complains Unreachable code detected.

Comment: @Bigeyes must be unreachable somewhere down in those other functions

Comment: Still not working. The third function is always running before the others. Perhaps I need to change it as promise as well

Answer (score 1):

```
private functionOne() {
   return new Promise((resolve) => {
    this.service['user'].get().subscribe(resolve);
  });
}

private functionTwo() {
   return new Promise((resolve) => {
    this.service['name'].get().subscribe(resolve);
  });
}

private loadingData() {
   Promise.all([functionOne(), functionTwo()]).then(([user, name]) => {
      this.user['d'] = user;
      this.name['d'] = name;
   }).then(() => this.syncFunctionThree())
};
```

By looking at the method signature if the `this.service['user'].get()` is an rx observable. you can use `this.service['user'].get().toPromise()` to get the promise directly. if the `this.service['user'].get()` has multiple values try `this.service['user'].get().pipe(first())` instead